# KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset error in react-native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, textinput, react-functional-component

I used `keyboardVerticalOffset` to use Static Button in `KeyboardAvoidingView` of react-native.
but

[image: please read my image]

The red arrow is showing the unexpected behavior.
As you can see extra space is being added but it's a white area.

here is my code.

```
const Code = () => {
  const emailInput = useRef(null);
  const birthInput = useRef(null)
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');


  const scrollToEmail = () => {
// I want to scroll the y position of the scroll to the center where the TextInput's cursor is focused.
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex: 1}} behavior={'height'} keyboardVerticalOffset={73 + 50}>
        <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" ref={scrollViewRef}>
          
          <InputBox> <== height: 50
            <TextInput
              ref={emailInput}
              onFocus = {() => scrollToEmail()} 
          />
          </InputBox>
        
          <InputBox> <== height: 50
            <TextInput
              ref={birthInput}
              onFocus = {() => scrollToBirth()}
            />
          </InputBox>
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, width: '100%'}}>
        <BottomBtn check={check} onPress={submit} text={`ok`} /> <== height: 73
      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Code;
```

and `<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'padding'} keyboardVerticalOffset={73}/>` is not working. The keyboard closes immediately.

I would like the space for the Sticky button and TextInput to fit perfectly. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `KeyboardAvoidingView` with height before on a scrollview too but got the same result. My suggestion is to try different `behaviour`, but I think its better to use [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view). It has more properties and its easier to use.

Comment: But i need "ref" in scrollView. KeyboardAwareScrollView is useful but it is difficult to use ref

Comment: I don't want to find KeyboardAvoidingView's replacement. I want a solution